# How to calculate the dominant eigenvalue of the Hessian matrix?

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions, hessian-matrix

Now, I'm using L-BFGS method to solve the minimization problem of
$\phi = \phi_d + \phi_m$. The problem is ill posed and large scale, so it is necessary to use the approximation of the Hessian matrix to precondition it.

The hessian of $\phi_m$ is easy to compute, but the Hessian of $\phi_d$ is almost impossible to compute, so I want to use $\nabla^{2}\phi_m + \beta I$ as an approximation of $\nabla^{2}\phi$, where $\beta$ is the dominant eigenvalue of $\nabla^{2}\phi_d$. I can only compute the matrix-vector product of $\nabla^{2}\phi_d$ and an arbitrary vector, so is there an method to compute $\beta$?

Comment: Can you use the power iteration method ? (Compute $v\leftarrow A\dfrac v{\|v\|}$, until convergence of $\|v\|$.)

Comment: I have not try it yet. And the Hessian matrix is ill-conditioned, does it will converge in several iterations? Compute the matrix-vector product is very expensive.

Comment: Lookup the method on Wikipedia.

Comment: I thought you want to apply l-bfgs. Why are you approximating the hessian of $\phi_d$ by $\beta I$ instead of bfgs updates?

Comment: I want to use $\nabla^{2}\phi_m + \beta I$ as the initial approximation of the L-BFGS update, so the problem may be better conditioned.